# DUP operator, missuse?

Tags: assembly, masm

So Im beginning assembly and im trying to create a array of data

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section   .data 
HELPER_DATA: .byte 189 DUP (0)
x1:  .byte 0
x2:  .byte 1
x3:  .byte 2

    .text
    .section    .rodata
ftm1:   .string    "%d\n"
    .globl    main
    .type    main,    @function
main:
```

on line 3 Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `D'
everything else dosent give an error

its very hard for me to find a specific reference guide/manual to look things up with. Ive seen x86, x64, x86-64, masm, nasm, tasm, yasm, then a bunch of stuff for assembly inside C language variations and tbh im overwhelmed.

So to try and give some sort of idea of which im using.
gcc -m64 -masm=intel -o executable file.s
is what im typing into the terminal

inside the file its .intel_syntax noprefix and I dont see much else that would help any

Comment: Which assembly exactly are you using? Command syntax is consistent (modulo Intel/AT&T), but the directives are all over the place.

Comment: Im not too sure how to answer you.

Comment: It's a bit worrying that you can give a name starting with a dot to a section when at the same time directives already start with dots.

Comment: I assume by that your referring to ".data" after .section 

I was mimicking something we were given that worked .section .rodata

In any case the answer below suggested .section MyData, and it didnt help. Ive also just tried .data without the .section, same results

Comment: `.intel_syntax noprefix` is a GAS directive.  GAS Intel-syntax uses MASM-like syntax for *instructions*, but still uses GAS directives like `.space 183`.  `-masm=intel` means `-m` (machine option) `asm`(syntax flavor) = `intel`.  Nothing to do with the MASM assembler, so the `[masm]` tag is misplaced on the question.  But unfortunately the question has an accepted answer using MASM syntax, not GAS.  So that's a total mess, probably best to delete the whole thing, or post a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this

```
.section MyData
HELPER_DATA: db 189 DUP (0)
```

Comment: Ive tried that as well as DB. Removing the : give the error no such instruction.

Also HELPER_DATA: db 189 DUP (0) also gives the same no such instruction error.

Comment: based on the edited changes:

still gives Error: no such instruction: `db 189 DUP (0)'

Comment: MASM should have no problem with the single instruction `Here db 189 dup (0)` You should post a longer code snippet for us to review.

Comment: Could it be DUP is case-sensitive? Try lowercase.

Comment: lower case dup, still gives Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `d'

Comment: I looked up the GAS reference, https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ and Im not seeing DUP as a operator listed, so would I need to just

HELPER_DATA: .byte 0,0,0,0.......